# Can anybody help me in letter sample for a journal asking for permission to use figures in the paper?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, citations, journals

I'm a co-author in one paper and I would like to use some figures from this paper in my thesis, any tips how I can write to journal and what I should write on my letter?Usually, they accept or refused?

Comment: What does the copyright agreement from the publisher say? Despite all the restrictions, most agreements that I have come across said something about the authors retaining a right to re-publish content as a part of one's personal educational endeavours (in other words, in one's thesis for achieving a degree).

Comment: Have you looked at the journal publisher's website? Many have a blanket permission, or tell you exactly what form to use to ask - in some cases it's a two-minute formality to get a permission granted. It varies by publisher.

Comment: If you're in the US, then this almost certainly falls under fair use. Fair use is an important freedom, and if we don't use it, we'll end up losing it. This would apply even if you weren't a co-author of the paper, but the fact that you were a co-author makes this an even more reasonable thing to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a letter-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask. State clearly what paper the source is, who the authors are, which images are of interest and why. Explain what the use of the images will be, where you plan to publish the result. Ask for the exact way in which you should acknowledge the source.

As stated in comments, if the source of the images is your own paper or thesis, you'd need to check the agreement to publish those.

Make sure you cite the original source (your thesis, in this case) correctly.